# Calling methods within a class method in Python

Tags: python

I have found that when calling methods from within a method of a class I do not need to pass any variables to the method. Instead it simply inherits the attributes from that method when the method is called.

```
class Person(object):
    def method1(self):
        print(self.attr1)

    def method2(self):
        self.attr1 = 'attr1'
        self.method1()
```

This works for me. However, my first intuitive attempt consisted of the following nonfunctional code.

```
class Person(object):
    def method1(self, attr1):
        print(self.attr1)

    def method2(self):
        self.method1('attr1')
```

Even though I figured out a solution to the problem, I'm very much interested to learn the underpinnings behind this one.

EDIT: The example I am trying to understand is this:

```
class Converter(object):

    def split(self, x):
        self.a, self.b, self.z, self.c = self.x.split(' ')
        self.z = None
        self.a = int(self.a)

    def converter(self, unit, example):
        self.x = ''
        while self.x != 'exit':
            self.x = input("Type '50 %s' or similar, or type 'units' to view valid units; type 'exit' to return to the main menu: " % (self.example))
            if self.x == 'exit':
                break
            elif self.x == 'units':
                print(list(self.units.keys()))
            else:
                self.split(self.x)
                print(self.a / self.units[self.b] * self.units[self.c], self.c)

    def volume(self):
        self.units = { 'L': 1,
                       'mL': 1000,
                       'q': 1.05699,
                       'p': 2.11338,
                       'gal': 3.78541,
                       'oz': 33.814,
                       'ccm': 1000,
                       'cin': 61.024
                        }

        self.example = 'L to q'
        self.converter()
```

I don't understand why this wouldn't work:

```
class Converter(object):

    def split(self, x):
        self.a, self.b, self.z, self.c = self.x.split(' ')
        self.z = None
        self.a = int(self.a)

    def converter(self):
        self.x = ''
        while self.x != 'exit':
            self.x = input("Type '50 %s' or similar, or type 'units' to view valid units; type 'exit' to return to the main menu: " % (self.example))
            if self.x == 'exit':
                break
            elif self.x == 'units':
                print(list(self.units.keys()))
            else:
                self.split(self.x)
                print(self.a / self.units[self.b] * self.units[self.c], self.c)

    def volume(self):
        self.units = { 'L': 1,
                       'mL': 1000,
                       'q': 1.05699,
                       'p': 2.11338,
                       'gal': 3.78541,
                       'oz': 33.814,
                       'ccm': 1000,
                       'cin': 61.024
                        }

        self.converter({'L':2}, 'L to q')
```

EDIT2: Okay I think I understand now. The attributes are being attached to the instance object and I was simply not assigning the attributes that were passed onto the next function to the instance object.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  In the first example, you set `self.attr1 = 'attr1'`, so the attribute is there.  In the second example, you don't do that, so it isn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you phrase the question suggests you're misunderstanding how attributes work.  Attributes pertain to the *object* (an instance of a class), not to the method.  When you have a method like this:

```
def method2(self):
    self.attr1 = 'attr1'
    self.method1()
```

`self` refers to the instance that you are calling the method on.  For instance if you do `bob = Person()` and then `bob.method2()`, `self` will be the same object as `bob`.  When you do `self.attr1 = 'attr1'`, you set the attribute on that object.  If you then call `method1`, it has access to all the attributes on the object.  Any attributes you don't put there aren't there.

Simply put, if you never do `self.attr1 = whatever`, then trying to get the value of `self.attr1` will never work.  In your second example, you never do `self.attr1 = ...`, so there is no attribute `attr1` to get.

I agree with zehnpaard that you are confusing things by using the same label `attr1` as an attribute name (`self.attr1`), a local variable name (`attr1`), and a string value (`'attr1'`).  Change all of those to different things and you'll begin to see how they work differently.

Answer (score 2):

In the second (and non-functional) code, you were trying to call `self.attr1` from `method1`, but no such attributed existed for the Person object.
`method1` would have worked fine if it said `print(attr1)`, where `attr1` is the variable that got sent in as the second argument to `method1`

By the way, the new code would throw an error if someone tried calling `method1` on an object before `method2` was called.  This is because the Person object doesn't have an `attr1` attribute before `method2` runs.

Understanding what's going on becomes very difficult when you have similar names/string values for different things.  I would suggest using different names/values for `self.attr1`, `attr1` and `"attr1"`, and it will become much more obvious why your original code wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

In this:

```
class Person(object):
    def method1(self):
        print(self.attr1)

    def method2(self):
        self.attr1 = 'attr1'
        self.method1()
```

You have passed `self` into `method1` function which stands for an instance of `Person` class. After that, you can invoke `attr1` since you already have instance in `method1` namespace.

That's why you don't have to pass string `'attr1'` to `method1` again to print.